# Call function outside user control

Tags: vb.net

I need help to call a function in a usercontrol that is shown in a panel within the form, so far this is i tried, but no luck, i can't still get the text inputted on the textbox

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Dim ustudent As New StudentAdd
    ustudent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ustudent)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click       
            ustudent.SaveData() 
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

in user control have some textbox
textbox1 and textbox2

```
Public Class StudentAdd
    Public Sub SaveData() As Boolean
     'just testing whether it could work well
    ' getting textbox value
       MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)        
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: mainform]

[image: usercontrol]

Comment: Make it a public shared function... or just make it a public sub.. your returning a boolean do you or do you want to return the data?

Comment: How do you attemp to get the text? Does your usercontrol have a property or a function?

Comment: That should be a `Sub` not a `Function` if your not needing to get the return value.

Comment: @mercenary, you need to expand your description of the problem.  I setup an app like you have explained and it worked fine.  Click "Student" and the StudentAdd panel is added to Panel2.  Type values into TextBox1 and click the Save button and the message box showed the value I entered.  How is your result different?

Comment: @Gridly, I change it to Sub, still the same no return value on msgbox, what you describe is what I want to achieve, can you send me the app you made on rearintok@gmail.com

Comment: @Josh Part, the code above is  that all I use, no property just a Sub "SaveData", i just use msgbox temporarily just to confirm I getting the inputted text

Comment: What do you mean "no return value on msgbox"?  Msgbox displays a value.  Are you saying the msgbox is empty?  I can't send that code until tonight.

Comment: @Gridly, yes, the msgbox is empty, much appreciated if you send the code, so I can check what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

But ustudent is a local var, try to declare it outside link_clicked event. Do you want to create multiple user controls in the win or just one? 
For one you could add it at design time by dragging from the your project components panel
For more, you should implement some logic to identify the selected component and make it available for save data. If you want to save all just enumerate components in Panel2 (of type StudentAdd) and call the method

Comment: @Misterfredex, yes multiple usercontrols on one Panel2, for now it just one, so ill know if i can call a function correctly